# AS3 markup languages

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, actionscript

What options exist for rendering markup in Actionscript? I am looking for something I can use to write templates for menus, tooltips, and other display/frontend stuff in a Flash application.

I want to be able to load a template from a string, and then render it as a display object. The kinds of things that would go inside would include text, with possible font styles, text positioning, and images.

Comment: What sort of markup?  Need a bit more info here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flex dude! Flex all the way.
http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/

- 2 month free trial
- has massive example resource with [tourdeflex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html)
- Flex is just what you asked for. XML style front end language with AS3 for all your logic.
- Components made for menus, tooltips + Absolutely any UI component you need.
- Comes with its own IDE (There are others)
- Uber supported and is considered to be the business end of flash.
- Plus turn the same web app you've made into a native desktop app for linux, max, windows

---

You've also got Swing http://sourceforge.net/projects/aswing/

---

GAIA (very popular) http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/

- build flash apps in a website like fashion with pseudo 'pages' and components - with a flash panel that plugs into the Flash IDE

there are many more but these are the three I understand as the most popular. *Flex!*

Answer (score 1):

Try FTML: http://reshapemedia.com/ftml/ - flash text markup language... as3 and mxml in the browser.

Samples: http://reshapemedia.com/ftml/downloads/samples/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have in mind for workflow functionality, and configuratbility specifically, but some links to get started from could include:

The Flash Drawing API:
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/

Text Layout Framework:
http://corlan.org/2009/01/19/how-to-use-text-layout-framework-in-flex-32-or-air-15/
The new methods for flowing text and managing it for Flash Player 10

Using XML markup with the Text Layout Framework:
http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs5/gettext/index.html

Skinning Flex Components (Since they already have a lot of front-end functionality):
http://www.jamesward.com/2009/07/17/flex-4-example-halo-component-with-spark-skin/

I hope this reading list gives some starting points,